# Redirect subdomain to subfolder with IIS

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

I host my company website on a server:

```
www.example.com
```

And I have create a blog hosted with a blog hosting company that's on a separate server:

```
mynewblog.bloghostingcompany.com/[subpages]
```

How can I create an URL Redirect so I point to the blog from a subfolder on my own server:

```
www.example.com/blog/[subpages]
```

I have tried this in my web.config, but that changes the url to mynewblog.bloghostingcompany.com in the browser. I want to "point" to the external server but still see the subfolder in the browser.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name = "Blog URL Rewrite" >
            < match url="^blog/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
            <action type = "Rewrite" url="mynewblog.bloghostingcompany.com/[subpages]{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: take a look to this answer, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206814/how-to-create-dynamic-sub-domain-with-asp-net/9207119#9207119

Comment: @Aristos RewritePath changes the browser url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606252/why-rewritepath-changes-the-browser-url

Comment: Get the idea, use redirect, rewrite what ever you need...